# Best way to check if an object is null to prepare for mapping

Tags: java, null, mapping

I’m trying to map an object to another and I’m having trouble deciding what’s the best practice to check if the object from where I want to map is null

1 -

```
public DTOIntIdentityDocument mapIdentityDocument(Identitydocument in) {
        if (in == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            DTOIntIdentityDocument out = new DTOIntIdentityDocument();
            out.setDocumentType(this.mapDocumentTypeÇ(in.getDocumenttype()));
            out.setDocumentNumber(in.getDocumentnumber());
            return out;
        }
    }
```

2 -

```
public DTOIntIdentityDocument mapIdentityDocument(Identitydocument in) {
        DTOIntIdentityDocument out = null;

        if (in != null) {
            out = new DTOIntIdentityDocument();
            out.setDocumentType(this.mapDocumentTypeÇ(in.getDocumenttype()));
            out.setDocumentNumber(in.getDocumentnumber());
        }

        return out;
    }
```

¿Any ideas on what's the best practice to do this?

Comment: In the first example the `else` is not required. If the `if` passes, then it will `return null`. If not, it will simply continue and behave like an `else`.

Comment: It's a matter of personal coding practice. However if there are multiple points from where code might return, I prefer the second approach instead of  having multiple return statements scattered across the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, this boils down to style, thus there are no hard rules that tells us which version is "best". If all the code your team writes follows scheme 1, then that is the best code for you.

Having said that, I prefer a simple initial guard, followed by the code computing the "real" result, like this:

```
 if (in == null) 
     return null;

DTOIntIdentityDocument out = new DTOIntIdentityDocument();
out.setDocumentType(this.mapDocumentTypeÇ(in.getDocumenttype()));
out.setDocumentNumber(in.getDocumentnumber());
return out;
```

You want to write code that is easy to read and understand. Your version one has that *else* block ... that actually doesn't need to be in its own block, with additional indents. On the other hand, your second snippet is using three different layers of abstraction: a simple assignment, an if-block, a simple return. That is definitely "more complex" than option 1, or the modified code I used above. But note: option 2 has its advantages, too. If you want/have to trace/log the result of that method, with option 2, you add a single `trace(out)` right before the return statement.

And for the record: when you go "hardcore" clean code, the method would finally read:

```
if (in == null) 
     return null;

return createDocumentFrom(in);
```

or something alike. Meaning: you push that code that actually creates and configures the result object into its own private method. And that method doesn't need to worry about a null parameter being passed in!

Finally: the *ideal* solution does not need to have to worry about null parameters. Simply because you avoid null like the plague. Not always possible, but always desirable!

Comment: There was a great material explaining why we should stick to the most obvious and verbal return statements and if there are several scenarios that could lead you to the same return clause separate even those for readability.

Comment: @dbl I dislike "universal" rules. Every situation is a little bit different. Sometimes you have to sacrifice a lit bit of readability, for example to avoid code duplication. And the old "single entry single exit" principle still has its advantages. For example "option 2" from the OP works much better when you want to debug/trace that method, as the final result is easily accessible in the end via  that distinct **out** variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(in != null) 
   mapIdentityDocument(in)

public DTOIntIdentityDocument mapIdentityDocument(Identitydocument in) {
        DTOIntIdentityDocument out = new DTOIntIdentityDocument();
        out.setDocumentType(this.mapDocumentTypeÇ(in.getDocumenttype()));
        out.setDocumentNumber(in.getDocumentnumber());
        return out;

 }
```

Comment: What will happen if tomorrow another(the same) developer try to use that mapper and forget to check the param before passing it? This approach is proven not to work well for team with one or more members...